# multibyte characters in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to highlight characters from position 10 to position 15 in tkinter.The problem is that some of the characters are multibyte and in the gui it does not shade the position from character 10 to character 15 but the byte from display character 10 to display character 15.Therefore in the gui the following coloring starts before position 10 and ends before position 15

```
textPad.mark_set("matchstart", textPad.index("0.0 + 10 chars"))
textPad.mark_set("matchend", textPad.index("0.0 + 15 chars"))
textPad.tag_add(highlightType, "matchstart", "matchend")
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: Are the characters in the BMP, i.e., up to U+00FFFF? Tk is unicode-aware and has been for a long time, but currently only gets the BMP right (a known bug).

Comment: fwiw, `"0.0"` is invalid. It works, but the documented index of the first character is `"1.0"`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks. You are right.

Comment: @DonalFellows no it is not bmp. I copied from a webpage and pasted in my tkinter ScrolledText . It could be international characters

Comment: I'd like to see an example of what you are seeing and what you are expecting.

Comment: Tkinter does not have 'multibyte' characters as I believe you are using the term.  It has unicode codepoints in the range 0 to 2**16-1, in the old UCS-2 encoding in which each codepoint uses 2 bytes.  What unicode does have is glyphs composed from multiple codepoints.  For instance, 'a' with an accent or other subsidiary marking.  Some compositions have a codepoint themselves.  Others do not.  Python has functions to work with compositions, tk does not.  To mark 5 glyphs programmatically, you will have to scan codepoints left to right to convert codepoints to visible 'characters'.